# Loading XML to DataSet tables in .Net 4 / VS2010 not loading all elements /attributes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dataset

I am trying to load a complex XML document to DataSet Tables. Here is the code that validates the xml with xsd document and trying to load to the dataset tables:

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXmlSchema("test.xsd");
    ds.EnforceConstraints = true;
    ds.ReadXml("test.xml", XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
```

And after this I tried to see all table tables/ columns created using the below code"

```
       foreach (DataTable x in ds.Tables) {
            Console.WriteLine("TableName: {0}", x.TableName);
            foreach (DataColumn dc in x.Columns) {
                Console.WriteLine("   column: {0} , DataType: {1}", 
                            dc.ColumnName, dc.DataType);
            }
        }
```

In the printed Tables/columns output I could not see few elements / attributes that are in the XSD. When I moved around those Xs:element sections that are no in the output with the ones that are in the output, now the output shows the ones which were not earlier and did not show the ones which was there before... I would appreciate any help/ideas...

the xsd is about 50K and the xml is about 200K , not sure if they could be uploaded/pasted in here...

Thanks
Sankar

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to start with the DataTable you desire and then create the xsd schema from it:

As shown [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2009/01/05/create-an-xsd-schema-without-knowing-a-damn-thing-about-xsd.aspx).

Comment: the XSD comes with the XML document originated at a different place. I have no control over it. I have got to use that to validate the document..

Comment: You are sent both the XSD schema and the XML document and the XML document doesn't validate against the schema?  Maybe you could ask who's sending it to you to validate it BEFORE they send it.

Comment: The problem is not in XML document validating against the XSD. It's in the DATASET tables creation using the XSD.. The DATASET tables created using XSD obviously misses few elements and attributes. I could not find these elements / attributes either as a table or as an attribute in the tables created..  -- Thanks, Sankar